# Rails associated attribute label interpreted incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models called 'Page' and 'Area'

There relationships are as follows:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :areas

end

class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page

  attr_accessible :content, :name, :order, :title , :page_id

end
```

I have a view for creating the area in which I am accepting the page_id to associate the area to the page:

```
 <%= f.label :page_id %><br /> #this is being interpreted incorrectly
 <%= f.text_field :page_id %>
```

The form values in the action method are returned correctly with a page_id attribute. But on the html form the text value for the field is interpreted as "Page" rather than "page id".

Irrespective of the fact that this may not be a good practice or there is a work around of manually changing the value of the label; I need to understand why is this happening. Can someone please explain. Even when I use the debugger within the new action method of the Area controller the object @area shows page_id attribute correctly. I am assuming f.label is doing something weird here.

I am using rails 3.2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Rails will drop the _id in labels. The next param in f.label is a string that will be the label's inner html:

```
<%= f.label :page_id, "Page" %>
```

Outputs:

```
<label for="area_page_id">Page</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just how it works, Rails assumes that `something_id` should just become `something` when printed to forms. If you want to make it really "page_id" everywhere, open `config/locales/en.yml` and place this in there:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      area:
        page_id: "page_id"
```

And there you go, now it will be called `page_id` in this label and all the other places (including validations and all).

Comment: Although your answer is correct as well, I could only mark one as the preferred answer.